# Release Management - Change Connection String using Tokenize

Tags: tfs, web-config, tokenize, ms-release-management

I am hoping this is quite a straight forward question... from what I have found online, the best way to manage changing web.config connection strings through Microsoft Release Management is to use a tokanized web.config file (i.e. copy web.config and rename it web.tokenized.config) then tokanize the connection string.

What I havent been able to find out however is why a separate 'tokenized' web.config needs to be made... Is this file referenced over web.config? Is it bad practice to apply the tokenized parameter in the original web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F2%2F9%2FB%2F29B10D38-3473-4AC2-9CEB-7D471E0A8ECD%2FRelease%2520Management%2520for%2520Visual%2520Studio%25202013%2520User%2520Guide.pdf&ei=5ze-VIniN8TKmwXJ44LYCg&usg=AFQjCNHsnhwvSA_PNaGiQq6Y_Uf9Wj-zFw&sig2=RsoOkMuQLEcYNa14QKpKVQ&bvm=bv.83829542,d.dGY) "One version is your normal configuration file used during local development, and the other is a corresponding file that has the same content, except that instead of having local values for your variables, tokens have been put there. The build activity will swap those two files before doing the build, so that we end up with the tokenized version of the configuration files in the drop location."

In my view it's a painful maintenance overhead to maintain a copy of a configuration file as they have to be kept in sync. Much better if possible is to produce the tokenised config file as part of the build process. For web.config you can use the transformations functionality in conjunction with the **/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false** MSBuild argument. I have a blog post [here](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-tfs-preparing-deployment-pipeline/) that has the details.

Answer (score 0):

You need the "untokenized" version of web.config in order to debug/run the application locally from Visual Studio.

Comment: That makes sense... So when the project is published, will it know to use the web.tokenized.config instead of web.config? Do I need to set this somewhere myself?

Comment: During the build TFS will replace the token; you have to add the following MSBuild parameters to the build definition:

`/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false`

You can find more details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alming/archive/2015/01/19/using-web-config-transformations-and-release-manager.aspx)

Comment: This all sounds like exactly what I am after, and I have gotten really close to implementing it. I have setup my web.release.config, I have the matching connection string in my web.config... I have configured my build definition as explained in the example however when it gets into TFS I get the error that the package location cannot be found (when it tries processing the component. Interestingly if I take out the 2) Build --> Configurations value of Release / Any CPU then it builds and deploys successfully, but the web.release.config does not overwrite the web.config...? :( So Close!!

Comment: can any 1 tell me the simple way to replace values under web.cong file by using TFS release pipepline for production environment